# configure SSL in cluster of kubernetes

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, kubernetes, docker-image

I have used both links kubernetes in aws.

1) https://ramhiser.com/post/2018-05-20-setting-up-a-kubernetes-cluster-on-aws-in-5-minutes/

- with this link I successfully configure Kubernetes Cluster

https://codeburst.io/getting-started-with-kubernetes-deploy-a-docker-container-with-kubernetes-in-5-minutes-eb4be0e96370

- with above link I successfully deployed/pulled docker image from ecr to cluster

But problem is that I need to run app through HTTPS(ssl) protocol

we have docker image in aws ECR.we also have certificate key file and chain file for ssl.how do we configure it with kubernetes? so container will run in https

right now it's running like http://www.example.com .It's should be like
https://www.example.com

Process is like

1) push code in github (Done)

2) create docker image (Done)

3) push docker image to aws ECR (Done)

4) pull image from aws ecr and run with kubernetes cluster (Done)

6) work on http protocol on 80 port (done) http://www.example.com

7) bind domain to cluster end point(done)

8) configure SSL (Not done) https://www.example.com

Anybody have suggestions?

Comment: Can you share your deployment and service manifests in order to help

Comment: Can you give more detail what I need to share

Comment: the output  of `kubectl get all -o wide` command

Answer (score 0):

To run the application or setup SSL and TLS on kubernetes best practices suggest to use `cert-manager` & `ingress`.

Ingress works as the gateway and expose the service to the outside world and manage the connection.

While `cert-manager` use for manage the SSL certificates for domains. you can follow this guide to setup `ingress` and `cert-manager`:

> https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-an-nginx-ingress-with-cert-manager-on-digitalocean-kubernetes